# Не работают чебоксы в парах

Tags: html, css

Как заставить работать эти чебоксы, когда их несколько на странице? И можно как то перенести название чебокса справа налево что бы текст был "кликабельным"

```css
/* Cначала обозначаем стили для IE8 и более старых версий
т.е. здесь мы немного облагораживаем стандартный чекбокс. */
.checkbox {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}
/* Это для всех браузеров, кроме совсем старых, которые не поддерживают
селекторы с плюсом. Показываем, что label кликабелен. */
.checkbox + label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Далее идет оформление чекбокса в современных браузерах, а также IE9 и выше.
Благодаря тому, что старые браузеры не поддерживают селекторы :not и :checked,
в них все нижеследующие стили не сработают. */

/* Прячем оригинальный чекбокс. */
.checkbox:not(checked) {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox:not(checked) + label {
  position: relative; /* будем позиционировать псевдочекбокс относительно label */
  padding: 0 0 0 60px; /* оставляем слева от label место под псевдочекбокс */
}
/* Оформление первой части чекбокса в выключенном состоянии (фон). */
.checkbox:not(checked) + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background: #CDD1DA;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
/* Оформление второй части чекбокса в выключенном состоянии (переключатель). */
.checkbox:not(checked) + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  transition: all .2s; /* анимация, чтобы чекбокс переключался плавно */
}
/* Меняем фон чекбокса, когда он включен. */
.checkbox:checked + label:before {
  background: #9FD468;
}
/* Сдвигаем переключатель чекбокса, когда он включен. */
.checkbox:checked + label:after {
  left: 26px;
}
/* Показываем получение фокуса. */
.checkbox:focus + label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox">Я переключаю чекбокс</label><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox">Я переключаю чекбокс</label><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox">Я переключаю чекбокс</label><br><br>
```

Comment: Дать им разные значения `id` - .

Comment: размышлял по этому поводу, только не чё не получается, можно пример?

Answer (score 2):

```css
/* Cначала обозначаем стили для IE8 и более старых версий
т.е. здесь мы немного облагораживаем стандартный чекбокс. */
.checkbox {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}
/* Это для всех браузеров, кроме совсем старых, которые не поддерживают
селекторы с плюсом. Показываем, что label кликабелен. */
.checkbox + label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Далее идет оформление чекбокса в современных браузерах, а также IE9 и выше.
Благодаря тому, что старые браузеры не поддерживают селекторы :not и :checked,
в них все нижеследующие стили не сработают. */

/* Прячем оригинальный чекбокс. */
.checkbox:not(checked) {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox:not(checked) + label {
  position: relative; /* будем позиционировать псевдочекбокс относительно label */
  padding: 0 0 0 60px; /* оставляем слева от label место под псевдочекбокс */
}
/* Оформление первой части чекбокса в выключенном состоянии (фон). */
.checkbox:not(checked) + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background: #CDD1DA;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
/* Оформление второй части чекбокса в выключенном состоянии (переключатель). */
.checkbox:not(checked) + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  transition: all .2s; /* анимация, чтобы чекбокс переключался плавно */
}
/* Меняем фон чекбокса, когда он включен. */
.checkbox:checked + label:before {
  background: #9FD468;
}
/* Сдвигаем переключатель чекбокса, когда он включен. */
.checkbox:checked + label:after {
  left: 26px;
}
/* Показываем получение фокуса. */
.checkbox:focus + label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox1">Я переключаю чекбокс</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox1" /><label></label><br><br>
<label for="checkbox2">Я переключаю чекбокс</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox2" /><label></label><br><br>
<label for="checkbox3">Я переключаю чекбокс</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox3" /><label></label><br><br>
```

Как было сказано выше - разные id, у вас везде были id "checkbox", изменил на checkbox1, checkbox2 и checkbox3. И для label и для input тегов.

По поводу текста справа налево - сделал, но будьте внимательны, т.к. label участвует в стилях и я добавил пустые label теги.

Comment: Прошу прощения, в input ид сменил, а в label пропустил, из за этого всё и не работало

Comment: Я так и думал :) Почитать подробнее можно здесь http://htmlbook.ru/html/label

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо дать разные `id` ,

`id` должен быть уникальный.